# Flipping Cards on Click & Increasing Score in Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so far I have gotten my flipped cards to show, unflipped cards behind my flipped cards showing the right letter. all that's left is to make it in a way that when I click on a card, it flips and reveals the flipped cards, then when I click on another card, the same thing happens but keeping in mind that.

Once a card is clicked, a 5-second timer begins for which if nothing else is done the card flips back but when a second card is clicked within this time and its a match, the score is increased if not the cards flip back.

The code of where I have gotten to is below;

```
    var game = new Phaser.Game(1000,750,Phaser.CANVAS,'gameDiv');

var background_pic;

var card_1;
var CardStacks;

var text;

var card_back;
var card_BackStacks;

// var firstClick, secondClick;
var score;
// var myCountdownSeconds;

// var array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'];
var array = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'K', 'K', 'L', 'L'];

// var flipSpeed = 200;
// var flipZoom = 1.2;


var mainState = {

    preload: function() {

        // game.load.image('backgrounds', "assets/bg.jpg");
        game.load.image('Card_1', "assets/cards/plain.png");
        game.load.image('Back', "assets/cards/back.png");
    },

    create: function() {

        game.add.text(380, 10, 'Sun-Tiles', 
            {fill : 'blue',
            fontSize : '50px'

        });

        score = game.add.text(800, 30, 'Score: 0', 
            {fill : 'white',
            fontSize : '20px'

        });
        

        card_1 = game.add.sprite(0,0, 'Card_1');
        card_1.anchor.setTo(0);
        card_1.visible = false; //sets original tile invisible by default.

        card_1 = game.add.group();
        card_1.enableBody = true;
        card_1.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

        createTiles();

        text = game.add.group();
        // text.enableBody = true;
        // text.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
        
        // var score = game.add.group();
        // score.add(game.make.text(10,10, "Score: " + 100,  { font: "32px Arial", fill: generateHexColor() }))


        card_back = game.add.sprite(0,0, 'Back');
        card_back.anchor.setTo(0);
        card_back.visible = false;  //sets original tile invisible by default.

        card_back = game.add.group();
        card_back.enableBody = true;
        card_back.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

        // card_1.event.onInputDown.add(this.finalScore, {'points':0}, this); //
    },

    update: function() {
        if (game.input.isDown)
        {
            turn();
        }
    }
}

// function countScore () {
// counting number of matches

//     //  Add and update the score
//     // score += 15;
//     scoreText.text = 'Score: ' + score;

// }

var shuffledCards =Phaser.ArrayUtils.shuffle(Array.from(array));

function createTiles() {
    for(var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
            CardStacks = game.add.sprite(x*160 + 20,y*160 + 90,'Card_1');

            card_1.inputEnabled = true;

            var style = { font: "100px Chiller", fill: "blue", wordWrap: true, wordWrapWidth: 150, align: "center"}; //The style to be applied to the text on cards.

            // Phaser.ArrayUtils.shuffle(array);

            // text = game.add.text(0,0, Phaser.ArrayUtils.getRandomItem(array), style);
            text = game.add.text(0, 0, shuffledCards.pop(), style); // shuffles cards and makes sure maximum of only 2 are produced. shuffles the array once, before your loop. Then, in the loop, remove one element for every card to prevent duplicates:

            text.x = 40; text.y = 20; //setting all the text to the right spot along the X and Y axis on the blank card.
            CardStacks.addChild(text); // making the text variable a child of the tile(blank card) variable. 

            card_BackStacks = game.add.sprite(x*160 + 20,y*160 + 90,'Back'); //to reveal the unflipped cards
        }
    }

    tween.onLoop.add(descend,this);
}

// function finalScore () { // function to increment score upon match
//  score.text  = 'Score: ' + (this.point + 10);
// }

game.state.add('mainState', mainState);

game.state.start('mainState');
```

can anyone help me with  the code please.

Comment: Looks like maybe the grid.left grid.right grid.top grid.bottom options https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#grid?

Comment: Since you did it with your other question too, in case you create any more questions around Phaser, the `phaser` tag is for Java, so you can just use `phaser-framework`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since if I were to write this I would end up refactoring much of your code - since you're reusing variables to store different objects (see `card_1` for example) - and your question is a little too large in scope for SO, suggestion on how to enable the `turn` function to trigger, and some general recommendations on how you might want to implement this in Phaser are below.

It appears that you have a gird of 4x6 cards. When creating these cards set `.inputEnabled = true;` on each sprite when you add them. You can then bind an event listener to each card, `turn` in your case: `.events.onInputDown.add(turn, this);`

Something like this:

```
// Since you're setting your text to the same style, this can be pulled out of your for loop.
var style = { font: "100px Chiller", fill: "blue", wordWrap: true, wordWrapWidth: 150, align: "center"};

for (var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        var individualCard = game.add.sprite(x*160 + 20,y*160 + 90,'Card_1');

        individualCard.inputEnabled = true;
        individualCard.events.onInputDown.add(turn, this);
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will allow you to remove what you have in the `update` function. Since you have sprites for each, there's no need to add a general handler for your input.

Since it looks like you're using Phaser 2, the [Click On An Image](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/basics/02-click-on-an-image) and [Bring A Child To Top](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/input/bring-a-child-to-top) official examples would be worth looking at for event handling and creating a group of items.

`console.log(arguments);` is my favorite way to determine what's being passed into the various functions when Phaser calls them, and you'll be able to see that you should be able to determine what card was clicked from the arguments passed.

You can of course add custom properties to the sprite after you've created it as well, or ideally (but more advanced) create a new type of object that extends Phaser.Sprite. If you use something like TypeScript, you'll need to do the latter.

In your `turn` function you can check to see how many cards are turned over already, if any, turn over the cards, determine if the cards are the same and increase the player score, and set/start/stop a Phaser timer, as needed. Given the scope of this, it would be best for you to give this a go yourself and ask another question if you run into code issues.

See the official [Custom Timer](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/time/custom-timer) and [Basic Timed Event](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/time/basic-timed-event) examples, as well as the [Phaser.Timer documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Timer.html).

If you run into code issues as you implement a timer that would be great as another question.

Comment: i found this link but when i try to incorporate what it into my code, obviously editing it to suit mine it doesnt work. but basically this is what i need. this i show i want to go about the clicking (asides the flipping which ill just call with a function i guess) and scoring aspect of this game. check the url: https://medium.com/@codemwnci/getting-started-with-phaserjs-2493e92b1b53

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Can you update your question with the specific issues you're having after looking at the link you provided and updating your code accordingly?

Comment: I'm working on the update. if it works then ill post the answer, if not then ill rephrase the question but basically all i need to do or add to the code is the enable the user click on a tile, when that is done, the card flips and reveals a letter for 5 seconds, if no other card is clicked within this 5seconds then it flips back to how it was. if another card is clicked it would check for a match, if there is a match, then points are gained, if not points are lost and both tiles flip back instantly. then all this is repeated again.